# Class Not Passing SObject By Reference

Tags: apex

I’m I created a class that consolidates SObject updates in my triggers. An issue that I am having is that when I call DynamicSObjectUpdater.getSObject(ID), it does not pass the SObject by reference. Is there something that I am missing here? What I am thinking is that when you return a Superclass (i.e. the SObject), it does not pass by reference.

The issue may lie in the following.

```
targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
```

I basically want to do the following:

```
Contact con = new Contact(ID=sObjectID);
```

OR

```
Account acc = new Account(ID=sObjectID);
```

OR
etc...

I was under the impression that

```
targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
```

Would do this for me. How do I go about achieving this? –

```
public with sharing class DyanmicSObjectUpdater 
{
    Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>>();

public SObject getSObject(ID sObjectID)
{
     SObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();
      if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot))
      {
        sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, SObject>());
      }
      SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(sot).get(sObjectID);
      if(targetSObject == null)
      {
        targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
        sorToUpdate.get(sot).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
      }
     return targetSObject;
   }
   public void updateSObjects()
   {
    List<SObject> sObjectsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();
    if(sorToUpdate.size() > 0)
     {
        for(SObjectType sorType: sorToUpdate.keySet())
        {
            sObjectsToUpdate.addAll( sorToUpdate.get(sorType).values() );
        }
      }
      System.debug(sObjectsToUpdate);
      if(sObjectsToUpdate.size()>0) update sObjectsToUpdate;
     }
   }
```

This is the class that calls the SObject Updater.

```
trigger Opportunity_Trigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) {

DynamicSObjectUpdater sObjectUpdater = new DynamicSObjectUpdater();

if(Trigger.OperationType == TriggerOperation.AFTER_UPDATE)
{
    UpdateOpportunityContacts.handleTrigger(Trigger.newMap, sObjectUpdater);
}

sObjectUpdater.updateSObjects();

}
```

Then the UpdateOpportunityContacts class

```
    public with sharing class UpdateOpportunityContacts 
{
public static void handleTrigger(Map<Id, Opportunity> newOppsMap, DynamicSObjectUpdater sObjectUpdater) {


        Map<Id, List<OpportunityContactRole>> conIdsWOpportunityContactRole = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityContactRole>>();

        for(OpportunityContactRole oppCon : [SELECT id, ContactId , Opportunity.StageName, OpportunityId, Role, Opportunity.Deal_Velocity__c FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId in : newOppsMap.keyset()])
        {
            if(!conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.containsKey(oppCon.ContactId))
            {
                conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.put( oppCon.ContactId, New List<OpportunityContactRole>());
            }

            conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.get(oppCon.ContactId).add(oppCon);
        }

        List<Contact> cons = QuerySelector.dynamicQuerySelector(conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.keyset());


        updateContactOutreachStatus(cons, conIdsWOpportunityContactRole, sObjectUpdater);


    }


public static void updateContactOutreachStatus(List<Contact> cons, Map<Id,  List<OpportunityContactRole>> conIdsWOpportunityContactRole, DynamicSObjectUpdater sObjectUpdater)
{

    for(Contact con: cons)
    {
        Contact conToUpdate = (Contact) sObjectUpdater.getSObject(con.Id);

        // we only care about the first element in the array
        if( conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.get(con.Id)[0].Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Won' || 
            conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.get(con.Id)[0].Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Won (Non-Annual Contract)')
        {
            conToUpdate.Outreach_Status__c = 'Current Client';
            conToUpdate.Deal_Velocity__c   = conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.get(con.Id)[0].Opportunity.Deal_Velocity__c;
        }
        else if(conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.get(con.Id)[0].Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Lost')
        {
            conToUpdate.Outreach_Status__c = 'Closed Lost';
            conToUpdate.Deal_Velocity__c   = conIdsWOpportunityContactRole.get(con.Id)[0].Opportunity.Deal_Velocity__c;
        }
        else
        {
            conToUpdate.Outreach_Status__c = 'Opportunity';
        }  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The premise of this question seems to me to be mistaken in identifying the issue as pass-by-reference semantics.

I pasted the `DyanmicSObjectUpdater` class unaltered in my Developer Edition and ran the following Anonymous Apex:

```
Id contactId = '0033600001gyv5BAAQ'; // This is a real Contact
DyanmicSObjectUpdater s = new DyanmicSObjectUpdater();
Contact c = (Contact)s.getSObject(contactId);
c.FirstName = 'TestSobjectUpdater';

s.updateSObjects();
```

Contact `0033600001gyv5BAAQ` was updated exactly as expected.

My suspicion is that the updates you believe are being lost are not being persisted because you are holding a reference to an instance of `DyanmicSObjectUpdater` in a `static` variable somewhere but don't call `updateSobjects()` at the right point, resulting in your instance being reset at a transaction boundary - or at least a problem similar to that structure.

(Also, `Dynamic` is misspelled - this drives me crazy in my own code).

Comment: I added in the class that calls it in the question. Maybe its because I call it within a for loop?

Comment: Also sorry for the misspelling! lol

Comment: @MatthewMetros Shouldn't have anything to do with a loop. Is that your whole trigger? Why are you executing on so many trigger events?

Comment: Can you build a small, reproducible example of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html), SObjects (and other non-primitives) are actually passed by value but happen to behave like pass by reference, unless you call `new` or the equivalent:

> Non-primitive data type arguments, such as sObjects, are also passed into methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the passed-in argument still references the same object as before the method call, and can’t be changed to point to another object. However, the values of the object’s fields can be changed in the method.
>
> The behavior nearly always appears like non-primitives are passed by reference, and you would rarely notice that they are actually not passed by reference.  However, when you act on the variable itself in the method, **like calling “new” on it**, you will notice that *things do not behave in pass-by-reference fashion*.

I believe this line of code is giving the pass by value behavior:

```
targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);
```

Comment: targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);

I basically want to do the following:

Contact con = new Contact(ID=sObjectID);

I was under the impression that 

targetSObject = sObjectID.getSobjectType().newSobject(sObjectID);

Would do this for me. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean "unless you call new or the equivalent". Are you saying "New" keyword turns it into a pass by reference?

Comment: I didn't test myself, just noticed what the article was saying - look at the bold and italics at the end of the quote above.  Either way, I think I'm missing the bigger picture - what's the issue when you return `targetSObject` upwards?  Maybe show some relevant code at that level?

Comment: targetSObject doesnt pass by reference

Contact conToUpdate = (Contact) DynamicSObjectUpdater.getSObject(con.Id);

conToUpdate.Name = 'Bob';

that will not change the value of the sobject in:

Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>>();

Comment: Why do you need by reference?  If the whole sobject is there, with the Id, then what's the difference?  Again, showing some code example on that level might help

Comment: I passed in the class, which explains why I need it to return passed by reference. I want to be able to make changes to the SObject outside of the class, with the idea that when I call UpdateSObjects, that the changes recorded outside of the class are recorded and then updated.

Comment: I'm playing with your code locally..  So far as I can tell, it works exactly as expected (the map on SOR_DyanmicSObjectUpdater gets the values assigned in updateContactOutreachStatus) .... The only "hickup" I had was when I submitted a malformed OpportunityContactRole map, in which case the assignments were not being made at all.

Comment: I am not understanding why it is not updating on my end. I uploaded all my code that leads to the actual update. Not sure if you have time to check it out, but if you do let me know how it goes. Trying to configure a workaround in the meantime.